# Arduino Uno as Xbox One Controller?

Tags: arduino-uno, remote-control

I’m very new to Arduino and have been doing a lot of research on how to connect my Arduino Uno to my Xbox One as a wired controller, unfortunately I haven’t been able to find much help.  I found UnoJoy but it seems to only work with PlayStation.  I know that it is possible because the Uno has HID.  I’m sorry if this has been answered before, but how do I code the Uno so the Xbox will recognize it so I can assign (push buttons, toggle switches, rotary encoders) to certain functions in game?

Comment: The Uno **does not** normally have HID.  It is true that USB its interface chip can be reprogrammed to do that, but it's complicated and complicates normal operation.  You'd be better of with a *direct* USB board like a Leonardo or something else based on a 32u4, or something based on a suitable ARM part like most of the Teensy series.

Comment: I expect if you do some research you will find there is a body of knowledge on fully custom game controllers.  Actually had some unrelated boards assembled once by someone who had invested in short-run assembly equipment in order to serve that market.